# Wrap FindElement() from another element into a wait in selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I want to wait for presence of an element found in search context of another element.

For example I might want to search contents of a particular modal window (I might have more than one in DOM, I want the second one).

```html
<body>
  <div class="modal class1 class2">
    <div class="content class3 class4">Stuff</div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal class1 class2">
    <div class="content class3 class4">Stuff2</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

So what I'd naturally want to do is to find modal window by `modal` class with a wait:

```
var locator = By.CssSelector("div.modal:nth-child(2)");
var modal = new WebDriverWait(currentDriver,defaultTimeout)
                .Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(locator))
```

and then look for contents by `content` class within the modal element:

```
var content = modal.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.content"));
```

The problem is that in our app under test the presence of the modal doesn't mean the presence of its contents, which would fail the test with an exception at best if it's written like above.

So is there anyway to wrap `FindElement` from an element into a wait? It seems waits take their driver as their search context and only it (it's `WebDriverWait` after all), so I can't use it with an partial selector which is used for FindElement. Am I missing something?

I know I can use XPath to wait for contents directly, but its a lot of ugly repeating XPath, one for each content element. And I don't want to use implicit waits since we already have explicit ones and they don't live well together.

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared your code seems near perfect. However there is a *pitfall* for which you are seeing the *exception*. You can use the following code block to achieve the same :

```
var modal = new WebDriverWait(currentDriver,defaultTimeout).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("div.modal.class1.class2:nth-child(2)")));
```

I am not sure what exactly you meant by `look for contents` but to retrive the text **Stuff2** you can use the following line of code :

```
var content = new WebDriverWait(currentDriver,defaultTimeout).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("div.modal.class1.class2:nth-child(2)"))).GetAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap FindElement ??
Are you talking about this

```
 static class WaitObj
 {
      public static IWebElement FindElement(this IWebDriver driver, By by, int seconds)
      {
           if (seconds > 0)
           {
               var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));
               wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(by));
           }
           return driver.FindElement(by);
      }
 }
```

you can use the above code as

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ID"),10);
```